# HashMap showing only one key value

Tags: scala, hashmap

Below is the code where I am putting Address for two different keys but I am getting only one key value i.e for "ADDRESS_HOME".

I don't know if "ADDRESS_MAIL" is replaced or what.

```
  var homeAddress = new Address
  var mailAddress = new Address

  homeAddress.setAddressLine1(recordString(EmployeeJobMetadata.homeAddressLine1.id))
  mailAddress.setAddressLine1(recordString(EmployeeJobMetadata.mailAddressLine1.id))

  var addressMailMap = new HashMap[String, Address]
  addressMailMap.put(mailAddress.ADDRESS_MAIL, mailAddress)

  var homeAddressMap = new HashMap[String, Address]
  homeAddressMap.put(homeAddress.ADDRESS_HOME, homeAddress)

  employeePersonalData.setAddressMap(addressMailMap)

  employeePersonalData.setAddressMap(homeAddressMap)
```

Pojo class:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
class EmployeePersonalData {

@BeanProperty
var firstName: String = _

@BeanProperty
var lastName: String = _

@BeanProperty
var addressMap: Map[String, Address] = _ 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating and adding to two separate HashMaps (`addressMailMap` and `addressMailMap`), then assigning them both to the same field (via `setAddressMap`) in `employeePersonalData`:

```
employeePersonalData.setAddressMap(addressMailMap)
employeePersonalData.setAddressMap(homeAddressMap) // ref to addressMailMap is replaced by ref to homeAddressMap
```

If you wish for both addresses to be in one map, then you should only instantiate one hashmap and put addresses into it.